# Finding a fixed point of function without a closed-form solution

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to find a fixed point of a function that does not have a closed-form solution (it is the solution to a NMaximize problem). The following simplified problem, which would have an easy solution, produces the same issue. How can I fix it?

````
ClearAll[f, f1, f2]
f[a_, b_] := -a*e^2 - b*e + c
f1[a_, b_] := e /. NMaximize[-a*e^2 - b*e + 2, e][[2]]
f2[a_] := Solve[f1[a, b] - b == 0, b]
f2[1]

NMaximize::nnum: The function value -1.31267-0.829053 b is not a number at {e} = {-0.829053}.

ReplaceAll::reps: {e} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.

ReplaceAll::reps: {e} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
```
````

Answer (score 2):

The function `f2` is undefined for `a == 0`

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Gloal`*"]

f1[a_, b_] := MaxValue[-a*e^2 - b*e + 2, e]
f2[a_] = Solve[f1[a, b] - b == 0, b] // Simplify
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[b /. f2[a]], {a, 0, 5},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 18}},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"a", "b"}),
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.35, .75}]]
```

[image]

```
f2[0]

{}

Limit[#, a -> 2, Direction -> "FromAbove"] & /@ (b /. f2[a])

{4, 4}
```

Comment: Thanks, My bad. The problem remains trying to evaluate f2[1]. The solution should be b=0.

Comment: `f2[1]` is also undefined (note the [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) with `a > 2`)

Comment: It seems to me that a fixed point exists for a=1: try this 
Plot[f1[1, b] - b, {b, -1, 1}], solution at zero; however, Solve[f1[1, b] - b == 0, b] can't find it. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to include the `PlotRange`, i.e., `Plot[f1[1, b] - b, {b, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 3.5}]` to see that there is no solution.

Comment: I'm looking for a zero of f1[1,b], so why would I start the PlotRange at 0? Try PlotRange{-3,3} you'll see that f1[1,0]=0, so the solution is 0.

Comment: You need to include `0` in the `PlotRange` (whether `{0, 3.5}` or `{-3, 3}`) to make it clear that `f1[1, b] - b` never reaches `0`. Alternatively, `MinValue[f1[1, b] - b, b]` evaluates to `1`

Answer (score 0):

```
f1[a_, b_] := MaxValue[-a*e^2 - b*e + 2, e]


zwang = Simplify[f1[a, b] == b, {a > 0, b > 0}]
NMinimize[{a^2, zwang }, {a , b }]
(*{4., {a -> 2., b -> 4.00001}}*)

Show[ContourPlot[f1[a, b] == b, {a, 0, 5}, {b, 0, 15}],Graphics[Point[{a, b} /. mini[[2]]]]]
```

[image]